# How to creat datatable with sql in vs using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have created Experiments DataTable using vs designer. But when I try to insert , got exception :

> "Message = "Invalid object name 'Experiments'."".

[image]

```
    public void InsertLog(string date, string exID, string name)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable t = con.GetSchema();
            try

            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO Experiments VALUES(@Date, @ExID, @Name)", con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Date", date));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ExID", exID));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", name));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("Can not insert.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right click the project > Add New Item > DataSet

Comment: @japz: does it creates an sql table?

Comment: First, I don't recommend creating tables with table names and column names in Chinese, it's hard to maintain, Second, are you sure you're connecting to right database, the error message is saying there's no experiments table in the database (Typo?)? Third, you're using ADO.net, then what's the use of adding the entity framework?

Comment: @un-lucky nope, the OP is asking how to create data table, to create data table , he needs to create a datasets.. sql table will be created inside the SQL server itself.

Comment: I think op is asking to create sql tables from visual studio.

Comment: @un-lucky, the OP says `How to create datatable with sql in vs using C#?` not How to create SQL table using vs.

Comment: @Jiada, it seems that your problem is not in the dataset/datatable , because ther error says `Invalid object name 'Experiments` , maybe the table `Experiments` did not existing on your database ?

Comment: He's clearly trying to insert a record into a log table.  You really should attempt to read the code sample provided before being a hero.

Comment: He's trying to insert records into a table with NO PRIMARY KEY defined.

Comment: I have try to set primary key,but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you created table named "Experiments" in database ?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you asking,

But if you want to create a Data Table in C# use the following code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

optionally you can pass through the table name in the parenthesis.

If you want to create a SQL Table you can do the following:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Connection String Here"))
        {
            cn.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCommand
                (
                    "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] " +
                    "( " +
                    "[Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    "[MyColumn] VARCHAR(50) NULL " +
                    ")",
                    cn
                );

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

change as necessary.

To add columns at a later stage, you can use the same method except change your Create Table SQL script to an Alter Table SQL Script.